# Using void return types with new Func<T, TResult>

Tags: c#, generics

I'm using an anonymous delegate in my code calling this example function:

```
public static int TestFunction(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

The delegate looks like this:

```
var del = new Func<int, int, int>(TestFunction);
```

My question is: how do you specify a `void` return type for `TResult`? The following doesn't work:

```
public static void OtherFunction(int a, string b) { ... }
var del = new Func<int, string, void>(OtherFunction);
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If there is no return type, you want `Action<int,string>`:

```
var del = new Action<int, string>(OtherFunction);
```

or just:

```
Action<int, string> del = OtherFunction;
```

Answer (score 8):

You have to use Action< T > if you want to return void.

Answer (score 2):

You need Action< T > if you don't want to return something

Answer (score 0):

Use Action Instead of Func if you don't need any return value

```
    public void InvokeService<T>(Binding binding, string endpointAddress, Action<T> invokeHandler) where T : class
    {
        T channel = FactoryManager.CreateChannel<T>(binding, endpointAddress);
        ICommunicationObject communicationObject = (ICommunicationObject)channel;

        try
        {
            invokeHandler(channel);
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                if (communicationObject.State != CommunicationState.Faulted)
                {
                    communicationObject.Close();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                communicationObject.Abort();
            }
        }
    }
```