# Pass an argument to task in C++/CLI?

Tags: c++-cli, arguments, action, task

I have this code for the C# in Visual Studio 2012.

```
public Task SwitchLaserAsync(bool on)
{
   return Task.Run(new Action(() => SwitchLaser(on)));
}
```

This will execute `SwitchLaser` method (public nonstatic member of a class `MyClass`) as a task with argument bool on.

I would like to do something similar in managed C++/CLI. But I am not able to find out any way how to run a task, which will execute a member method taking one parameter.

Current solution is like this:

```
Task^ MyClass::SwitchLaserAsync( bool on )
{
    laserOn = on;   //member bool 
    return Task::Run(gcnew Action(this, &MyClass::SwitchLaserHelper));
}
```

Implementation of `SwitchLaserHelper` function:

```
void MyClass::SwitchLaserHelper()
{
     SwitchLaser(laserOn);
}
```

There must be some solution like in C# and not to create helper functions and members (this is not threadsafe).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the working answer.. Have tested it.. Passing an argument (int) to the action sampleFunction.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CLRSamples.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Threading;
using namespace System::Threading::Tasks;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;

void CLRSamples::sampleFunction(Object^ number)
{
    Console::WriteLine(number->ToString());
    Thread::Sleep((int)number * 100);
}

void CLRSamples::testTasks()
{
    List<Task^>^ tasks = gcnew List<Task^>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        tasks->Add(Task::Factory->StartNew((Action<Object^>^)(gcnew Action<Object^>(this, &CLRSamples::sampleFunction)), i));
    }

    Task::WaitAll(tasks->ToArray());

    Console::WriteLine("Completed...");
}

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    CLRSamples^ samples = gcnew CLRSamples();
    samples->testTasks();

    Console::Read();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you for answare, I have one question , how to pass multiple parameter to function,

Comment: @MilindMorey It's not possible to pass multiple parameters, so only solution for this is to pass a object (instance) of the class which has those parameters as instance variables.

Comment: thanks Viswanadh for your reply, I am trying to call multiple functions one by one , same as you r using for loop in above example , only differance is  I need to wait for some time and run next  task; any idea to run functions one by one with specific interval of time ?

Comment: @MilindMorey Sorry for the late reply, I din't follow up. I don't think I got your question right. But still I will answer for what I understood. Why not put a sleep inside the for loop before adding it to a task? Won't this work?

Answer (score 17):

There isn't yet any way to do this.

In C# you have a closure.  When your C++/CLI compiler was written, the standardized syntax for closures in C++ was still being discussed.  Thankfully, Microsoft chose to wait and use the standard lambda syntax instead of introducing yet another unique syntax.  Unfortunately, it means the feature isn't yet available.  When it is, it will look something like:

```
gcnew Action([this, on](){ SwitchLaser(on) });
```

The current threadsafe solution is to do what the C# compiler does -- put the helper function and data members not into the current class, but into a nested subtype.  Of course you'll need to save the `this` pointer in addition to your local variable.

```
ref class MyClass::SwitchLaserHelper
{
    bool laserOn;
    MyClass^ owner;

public:
    SwitchLaserHelper(MyClass^ realThis, bool on) : owner(realThis), laserOn(on) {}
    void DoIt() { owner->SwitchLaser(laserOn); }
};

Task^ MyClass::SwitchLaserAsync( bool on )
{
    return Task::Run(gcnew Action(gcnew SwitchLaserHelper(this, on), &MyClass::SwitchLaserHelper::DoIt));
}
```

The C++ lamdba syntax will simply create that helper class for you (currently it works for native lambdas, but not yet for managed ones).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is clear that lambda is not supported in managed code. Still I would like to avoid creation of the helper classes. What I have found in the documentation is the class Action<T> for managed C++. This should be capable to take a function with one argument but I wasn't able to use it and especially with a Task::Run method (or somehow use it with a Task class). Is there a solution without a helper class or helper methods?

Comment: @Bezousek: `Task::Run` requires an `Action` delegate.  No, an `Action<T>` isn't the same type.  Closures are implemented with a helper class.  This is what the C# compiler creates from your example code in your question, and this is what the C++/CLI compiler will do someday if managed lambda features are added.

Comment: Closures are Part of C++, and have no problem being used in a modern environment [amazing what a decade since the original question can change]

Comment: @DavidV.Corbin: To the best of my knowledge, C++/CLI still does not support creation of managed delegates from a closure.

Comment: @BenVoigt - Not directly, but a Lambda (with closures) can be native, then wrapped in an std:function, and then that function can be invoked from (parameterless) Action.. Sounds ugly, but is literally just 2-3 lines of code.

Comment: @DavidV.Corbin: Yes, you can make a helper "ActionTrampoline", bit of a hassle to support delegate types with parameters but that can be done too.

Comment: @BenVoigt - Agreed "a bit of a hassle". But still 2-3 lines rather than the additional classes/templates/et. al. that have been shown in the (now decade old) examples here. 

So my my perception, major progress (though still far from seemless). I do try to keep my C++/CLI down to minimal interop and not start "Slamming" /clr (or equiv) switch's rampantly in C++ code. Over the decades it has paid off pretty well.

Comment: But as recent async styles have become more common (not to mention explicit multi-threading) keeping cross thread synchronization has triggered a bit of an increas in interop boundary crossings in the applications/libraries I support. So for me, the simplere "all in one method" semantics has been a majorbenefit YMMV.

Comment: @DavidV.Corbin: The question asks about interop with C#.  So `/clr` is necessary, creation of a managed delegate is necessary.  Not for the entire program, but for this section.  And your 2-3 lines is also inaccurate.  Only one line of the code shown can go away (the one declaring `laserOn`, since the native lambda will capture that for you).  The rest is still needed.  The advantage of the approach you describe is that the 5-6 lines of code can be reused instead of differing per call-site.

Comment: @BenVoigt -- Looks like "/clr" may not be nexessare - "#pragma managed" may do the trick.

Comment: @DavidV.Corbin: The compiler will error if `#pragma managed` is encountered without running in `/clr` mode.

Answer (score 5):

Here's generic code I wrote this afternoon which might help (although it's not an exact match for this question).  Maybe this will help the next person who stumbles onto this question.

```
generic<typename T, typename TResult>
ref class Bind1
{
    initonly T arg;
    Func<T, TResult>^ const f;
    TResult _() { return f(arg); }

public:
    initonly Func<TResult>^ binder;
    Bind1(Func<T, TResult>^ f, T arg) : f(f), arg(arg) {
        binder = gcnew Func<TResult>(this, &Bind1::_);
    }
};

ref class Binder abstract sealed // static
{
public:
    generic<typename T, typename TResult>
    static Func<TResult>^ Create(Func<T, TResult>^ f, T arg) {
        return (gcnew Bind1<T, TResult>(f, arg))->binder;
    }
};
```

Usage is

```
const auto f = gcnew Func<T, TResult>(this, &MyClass::MyMethod);
return Task::Run(Binder::Create(f, arg));
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem when I wanted to provide a parameter to a task executing a method which does not return a value (retuns `void`). Because of that `Func<T, TResult>` was not an option I could use. For more information, please check the page [Using void return types with new Func](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4244359/679890).

So I ended up with a solution where I created a helper class

```
template <typename T>
ref class ActionArguments
{
public:
    ActionArguments(Action<T>^ func, T args) : m_func(func), m_args(args) {};
    void operator()() { m_func(m_args); };

private:
    Action<T>^ m_func;
    T m_args;
};
```

which is using `Action<T>` delegate to encapsulate a method that has a single parameter and does not return a value.

I would then use this helper class in a following way

```
ref class DisplayActivationController
{
public:
    DisplayActivationController();

    void StatusChanged(EventArgs^ args) { };
}


Action<EventArgs^>^ action =
    gcnew Action<EventArgs^>(this, &DisplayActivationController::StatusChanged);
ActionArguments<EventArgs^>^ action_args =
    gcnew ActionArguments<EventArgs^>(action, args);
Threading::Tasks::Task::Factory->
    StartNew(gcnew Action(action_args, &ActionArguments<EventArgs^>::operator()));
```

Approach using the helper class is probably not the most elegant solution, but is the best one I could find to be used in C++/CLI which does not support lambda expressions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using c++/ CLR, then make a C# dll and add reference to it

```
namespace TaskClrHelper
{
  public static class TaskHelper
  {
    public static Task<TResult> StartNew<T1, TResult>(
     Func<T1, TResult> func,
     T1 arg)
      => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => func(arg));

    public static Task<TResult> StartNew<T1, T2, TResult>(
     Func<T1, T2, TResult> func,
     T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
      => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => func(arg1, arg2));
  }
}
```

```
        bool Device::Stop(int timeout)
        {
            _ResetEvent_Running->Set();
            return _ResetEvent_Disconnect->WaitOne(timeout);
        }
        Task<bool>^ Device::StopAsync(int timeout)
        {
            auto func = gcnew Func<int, bool>(this, &Device::Stop);
            return TaskClrHelper::TaskHelper::StartNew<int,bool>(func,timeout);
        }
```