# How to gcnew Task which has an return value in C++/CLI?

Tags: c#, c++, task

I'm using Tasks on C++/CLI.
I would like to use MyTask(), wait for it until timeout, and get the return value.

However, I have no idea.

```
bool MyClass::MyTask(Object^ obj)
{
    MyClass^ my_obj = (MyClass^) obj;

    // Do something
    
    return true;
}

void MyClass::Method()
{
    //Task<bool>^ task = gcnew Task<bool>(gcnew System::Action<Object^>(&MyClass::MyTask), this); // This lin is invalid.

    //task->Start(); // I think I have to use Run() instead.
    
    bool result = await System::Threading::Tasks::Task::Run(gcnew System::Action<Object^>(&MyClass::MyTask), this); // This line is invalid.
}
```

Comment: The right solution is not to use C++/CLI. Switch to C#.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13071753/pass-an-argument-to-task-in-c-cli and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21033150/any-difference-between-await-task-run-return-and-return-task-run